# Expand function with arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: r

Lets say I have the functions `foo` and `bar` as follows

```
bar <- function(a, b) {
    # Some operations with a and b ...
} 

foo <- function(...) {
    test <- baz(bar(...))
    return (test)
}
```

Is there a function `baz` that returns the `bar`-call as a string with the arguments specified in `...` expanded? So, when i do

```
> foo(a = 1, b = 2)
```

i expect to get something like

```
[1] "bar(a = 1, b = 2)"
```

This can be done by pasting the arguments in `...`, but i would prefer some built-in solution that is more clean and nice.

---

So, say instead that `bar` is some pre-built function, `knitr::kable` in my case. How would I get the same result for this? For this say that `knitr::kable` has the same inputs as bar, i.e. `a` and `b`. The function foo now looks like this

```
foo <- function(...) {
    test <- baz(knitr::kable(...))
    return (test)
}
```

So I want the call

```
> foo(a = 1, b = 2)
```

to return something like

```
[1] "kable(a = 1, b = 2)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `foo` is given as in the question and both it and `bar` are not to be modified but rather you want to define a function `baz` which when called from `foo` as shown there returns the language object `bar(a = 1, b = 1)` then:

```
baz <- function(...) {
  mc <- substitute(list(...), parent.frame())
  mc[[1]] <- match.call()[-1][[1]][[1]]
  mc
}

# foo is copied from question without change
foo <- function(...) {
    test <- baz(bar(...))
    return (test)
}   

foo(a = 1, b = 2)
## bar(a = 1, b = 2)
```

Second example where `baz` is unchanged from above

```
# foo copied from question without change -- this is 2nd foo definition there
foo <- function(...) {
    test <- baz(knitr::kable(...))
    return (test)
}

foo(a = 1, b = 2)
## knitr::kable(a = 1, b = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match.call` with `deparse`

```
bar <- function(a, b) {
   deparse(match.call())
} 

foo <- function(...) {
    test <- bar(...)
    return (test)
}   

foo(a = 1, b = 2)
#[1] "bar(a = 1, b = 2)"
```

Comment: Nice! How would this be done for some pre-built `bar`? (see my updated question)

Comment: @itslwg I see...If the called function is wrapped with some other function using `match.call` isn't sufficient I guess.